# Angular 8 and Angular cli, "ng serve" problem with application including moment.js or popper.js modules

Tags: angular, angular-cli, momentjs, angular8, popper.js

I have created an app with angular 8 and cli with "ng new repro-app2" .
**The problem raise when** , after including moment.js module or popper.js module, I run "ng serve" from my pc to serve application locally (http://localhost:4200/). 
The console of the browser (firefox and chrome) throw this error:

```
moment.min.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'moment' of undefined
    at moment.min.js:1
    at moment.min.js:1
```

**The error disapear when** I build the same application running "ng build   --output-hashing=all" and I deploy the result on my webserver.

My angular.json file :

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "repro-app": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "app",
      "schematics": {},
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/repro-app",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
                "node_modules/moment/min/moment.min.js"
            ],
            "es5BrowserSupport": true
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "repro-app:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "repro-app:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "repro-app:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "src/karma.conf.js",
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [],
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ]
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "src/tsconfig.app.json",
              "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "repro-app-e2e": {
      "root": "e2e/",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "",
      "architect": {
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "repro-app:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "repro-app:serve:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json",
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "repro-app"
}
```

My package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "repro-app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~8.1.0",
    "@angular/common": "~8.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "~8.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~8.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "~8.1.0",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.2",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.801.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~8.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~8.2.0-next.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "~8.1.0",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "codelyzer": "^5.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.11.0",
    "typescript": "~3.4.5"
  }
}
```

Is possible to download the app from here:

[repro-app2](https://github.com/varolo/repro-app2/tree/master/repro-app2)

Comment: "node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js",

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. In this repro-app I do not use popper but only moment.js...

Comment: angular-cli uses webpack, review the webpack configuration for momentjs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `"node_modules/moment/min/moment.min.js"` from you `scripts` array in `angular.json` file.

The error will be vanished.

As you have installed moment.js using npm, wherever you want to use it, just import it as following in your component:

```
// app.component.ts
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import * as moment from 'moment';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'repro-app';

  currentDate = moment(new Date()).format('MM/DD/YYYY')

  constructor() {
    console.log(this.currentDate);
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks, this solved the issue. But any clue on why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

About popper.js. Was same issue when I updated app to 8 version of Angular. As a solution you can use Bootstrap minified bundle js file, it has popper.js already.

Need to change `scripts` array in `architect.build.options` section of angular.json. In final will be something like this:

```
"scripts": [
    "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
    "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js",
],
```

Hope, help you :)